# problem with concurrent updates on my database table

Tags: mysql, database

Different microservices might execute at the same time the following command on my database table

```
> update table_2 set final_date='23123123' where section_id=10
```

The section_id might have 50K rows. What might go wrong if multiple connection execute the same command (and same values)? How can I prevent a potential problem?

Comment: You should avoid this by synchronizing the various nodes in your application such that they all don't try to go and do the same logical update.  Actually, your MySQL database is one tool which you may use to synchronize your application.

Comment: how can MySQL help sync between pods?

Comment: You may create a table containing just a single row.  Any application which tries to do the update (and they all might...assuming the same logical trigger would exist in each node), it first tries to get a lock on this row.  Of course, only one node can get the lock, and your application would only attempt the update if the lock can be obtained.

Comment: MySQL looks after this kind of thing, its not Access you are using MySQL is a proper DBMS

Comment: @RiggsFolly the first will update the table (lock will occur). However the rest of the threads will try to do the same update after the first microservice ends the job.

Comment: Correct Captain. If that is a problem, then you have dont something wrong in either your database or application design

Comment: Captain, do you mean that other updates may change the `final_date` to another value before you have had time to do something with this date value?

Comment: There is definitely a problem between my chair and my keyboard. However if my query become update table_2 set final_date='23123123' where section_id=10  and final_date=old_date what will happen with the 2nd, 3rd, 4th thread?

Comment: Well thay should fail to make the update because the `final_date` will no longer match the `old_date`

Answer (score 0):

Obviusly if the command will execute multiple times this will cause you having a headache because you will not get what you want. So try to determine the logic before then apply it correctly.For example you can decide to take only the first change that arrive and discard the others after catching them (you can give a message like 'record locked can't be modified!').

Answer (score 0):

First, nothing will go "wrong" in your application.  (unless you somehow exceed the maximum connections allowed by either the database or your application)  The database itself will handle not allowing multiple connections to "update" the same row at "the same time".  Unless you explicitly state otherwise in your SQL statement, the default locking mechanisms will force your multiple attempts to update the same row into a queue.

Now your concern is the data integrity.  Determine what IS a problem, and what ISN'T, trying to fix your application layer to prevent multiple nodes firing the same request at the same time may not be worth the time and trouble if just letting the database manage multiple requests delivers a suitable result.

I offer several solutions that will reduce the number of UPDATES executed but not the number of connections your application will use to the database.

Add more logic to your UPDATE statement - for example only update if the existing value for final date is more than 5 sec old (or 5 minutes, or 5 hours, whatever fits your use case).  It should not have to be a large value because these statements would execute quickly if requested at the same time by the application nodes.

AND/OR checkout "skip locked" here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

it will essentially take the first node's request and then all others that attempt an update simply stop if they attempt to update while the row is locked.  This could take the place of the logic above, but only for requests that occur WHILE the row is already locked by a previous UPDATE.